# Change floating status for all floats in document

Tags: floats

Sometimes it's more convenient to have fixed floats during document creation (for ex. when copying from multiple MS Word documents) so as to not get lost and then at the end to be able to "release" them.

My question is: "How to achieve this without needing to replace every `H` specification of a float with `ht!` manually at the end of work (presuming you use `float` package and its' `H` specification for a float when writing the document)."

My try so far was to load `float` package and define two new commands.

```
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\floatingfloat}{\text{ht!}}
\newcommand{\fixedfloat}{\text{H}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[\fixedfloat]
    \caption {Some caption.}
    \label{tab:1}  
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rl@{}}
        \toprule
        Numbers & More umbers
        \midrule
        1 & 5 \\
        2 & 8 \\
        6 & 3 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This, however, returns an error: "Unknown float option ..."

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See if `\def\fps@figure{H}` in preamble (between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) can help you . After then (on the end) you can replace it with `\def\fps@figure{!htp}`

Comment: Thank you, both. I will, however, answer this question for the sake of simplicity and perhaps a more intuitive title.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zarko and @samcarter pointed out there is a simple way of doing this:

```
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{H}
\def\fps@table{H}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \caption {Some caption.}
        \label{tab:1}  
        \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}rl@{}}
            .
            .
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{"path"}
        \caption{Some caption.}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

During the actual document creation, we have to add the 5 lines in the preamble: `usepackage{float}, \makeatletter ...` to make floats "fixed". Then at the end we just replace the `H` with `ht!` or another position specification and recompile to have "floating" floats again.